# Galois Field implementation

Tags: digital-communications, digital

Just a quick question. What Galois Field is best if you need a minimum Hamming distance of $n$? I want to design a BCH generator polynomial that is acccording to this Hamming distance.

Answer (score 1):

This reference provides specific implementations for three error correcting BCH generators with a minimum hamming distance of 7

[BCH codes](http://web.ntpu.edu.tw/~yshan/BCH_code.pdf)

Note, also refer to [Peterson's Table of Irreducible Polynomials](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~lomonaco/f97/442/Peterson_Table.html) which lists all primitive and irreducible polynomials over GF(2):

Comment: Thank you! What if my message is 16 bits, can I use a GF (2^6) for a k = 16 bits even though my dmin is still at 7?

Comment: @LeBlancLord See the first page of the first link which outlines the block length n, the number of parity bits and minimum distance for a t-error corecting BCH code. In your case t=3, the minimum distance is >=7 and the number of parity-check digits is <= mt where the block length = $2^m-1$. With t small, n-k is exactly mt. So solving this for t=3 and k=16 results in m=5. So if I did that correctly you would have 16 message bits, and 3m=15 parity bits for a block length of 31, and dmin is 2t+1=7. Do you agree?